# Metamask export all acounts at once

Tags: metamask

Is there a way to export all metamask accounts at the same time and then load them in some other browser ?

Say for eg I have around 20 accounts in metamask in firefox and then I want to load these accounts at once from firefox to chrome. And these accounts are not generated from the mnemonic phrase. All of them have been imported from keystore json files.

Answer (score 2):

The mnemonic phrase (12 words) you can export from MetaMask is used to derive all accounts. If you import it into MetaMask in another browser or computer, you can simply create all accounts again, and you will get the same addresses.

If you don't have your mnemonic phrase yet, you can find it in Settings > Security & Privacy > Reveal Seed Words. Make sure to [properly back it up](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/backup-restore/how-to-save-back-up-your-wallet) in case something happens to your computer.

Comment: I have created just one account via the mnemonic phrase and I dont use it. All the other accounts I have imported from keystore json files. I have those keystore json files.But it would be nice if i could just export all the accounts from metamask in one browser at once and import it to another browser. Seems like at this stage i have to do it one account at a time.